# Specify format of Timestamp written by pyspark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, timestamp, pyspark, emr

Background is a simply pyspark programme that I developed on 1.6 using databricks csv read/writer, and all was happy. My dataframe had a timestamp column, which was written out in a standard `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format.

```
foo,bar,2016-10-14 14:30:31.985
```

Now I’m running it on EMR with Spark 2, and the timestamp column is being written as an **epoch in microseconds**. This causes a problem because the target (Redshift) can’t natively handle this (only seconds or milliseconds).

```
foo,bar,1476455559456000
```

Looking at [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv), it seems I should be able to specify the format used with `timestampFormat`, but I just get an error :

```
TypeError: csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timestampFormat'
```

Am I calling this wrong, or does the option not exist? Any other way to cleanly get my timestamp data out in a format that's *not* microseconds (milli would be fine, or any other standard time format really)

---

Simple code to reproduce:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('foo','bar')]).withColumn('foo',pyspark.sql.functions.current_timestamp())
df.printSchema()
df.show()

# Use the new Spark 2 native method
df.write.csv(path='/tmp/foo',mode='overwrite')

# Use the databricks CSV method, pre Spark 2
df.write.save(path='/tmp/foo2',format='com.databricks.spark.csv',mode='overwrite')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the docs I was look at were for 2.0.1, whereas I was running on 2.0.0 -- and `timestampFormat` is new in 2.0.1.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, Did you figure out how to write the timestamp in the standard format other than the epoch format, thanks.

Comment: @msounthar I ended up avoiding the issue by just treating it as a string throughout the job, since I didn't need to manipulate it within the processing.

Comment: Lucky you!, apparently its a spark 2.0.0 issue and its been fixed in 2.0.1 but EMR only supports 2.0.0 as of now.
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14279